# Access Violation when loading memorystream

Tags: c++, datasnap, tstream

Please help, I don't know what I am doing wrong.

I am developing an application that retrieves files from a server machine, for autoupdate the client machines. this is what I came up with:

```
void TAutoUpdate::CarregarDados()
{
   try{
      TQuery* Q = new TQuery(NULL);
      Q->DatabaseName = "Base";
      Q->SQL->Add("SELECT * FROM UPDATE_MODULES WHERE DT_UPDATE > " + QuotedStr(ReadIni("ICDNetXP", "AutoUpdate", "DataUpdate", "12/30/1899")));
      Q->Prepare();
      Q->Active = true;
      Q->First();

      MemoryStream = new TMemoryStream;
      MemoryStream->Seek(0, soFromBeginning);

      SQLConnectionServer->Connected = true;
      TSMClient* Servidor = new TSMClient(SQLConnectionServer->DBXConnection);
      TDateTime maiorDataUpdate;
      String caminho;
      while(!Q->Eof){
         MemoryStream->Clear();

         if(maiorDataUpdate < Q->FieldByName("DT_UPDATE")->AsDateTime)
            maiorDataUpdate = Q->FieldByName("DT_UPDATE")->AsDateTime;

         caminho = "";
         caminho += Q->FieldByName("PATH")->AsString + Q->FieldByName("NOME")->AsString;
         MemoryStream->LoadFromStream(CopyStream(Servidor->GetAtualizacaoSistema(Q->FieldByName("ID")->AsString))); //here the error occours on 2nd execution of the while block
         MemoryStream->Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
         MemoryStream->SaveToFile(caminho);
         Q->Next();
      }
   }catch(Exception & e){
      MessageDlg(e.Message, mtError, TMsgDlgButtons() << mbOK, 0);
   }
}

TStream* TAutoUpdate::CopyStream(TStream* StreamIn)
{
      int BytesRead;
      System::PByte Buffer;
      const MaxBufSize = 1;
      TMemoryStream* StreamOut = new TMemoryStream;

      StreamIn->Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
      StreamOut->Seek(0, soFromBeginning);

      do{
         BytesRead = StreamIn->Read(Buffer, MaxBufSize);
         if(BytesRead > 0)
            StreamOut->Write(Buffer, MaxBufSize);

      }while(BytesRead > 0);

      StreamOut->Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
      StreamOut->SaveToFile("teste");
      return StreamOut;
}
```

So I want to know why this code works, but only on first iteration with the while. The results of the query are right, and the code loads and saves alright, but only for the first result of que query. And a workaround for this to work would be nice.

Comment: Just some notes.  `Q` leaks.  Can you change `TQuery* Q = new TQuery(NULL);` to TQuery Q(NULL);` ?  `MemoryStream` also leaks;

Comment: @RichardCritten C++Builder Gives me an error and doesn't compile if I do
     TQuery Q(NULL); 

And what do you mean by leaks?

Comment: I guess I figured the memory leak you spoke about, @RichardCritten, and I think I made a not so right workaround. I put a free statement for the memorystream inside the while, this seems to work, but it doesn't feel right creating and freeing the memory stream every iteration.